# Why canvas gradient.addColorStop() isn't centered when the gaps between stop values are equals?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Pretty self explanatory : https://jsfiddle.net/9hbx2nz7/

```
let gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,200,0);
gradient.addColorStop(0.125, "red");
gradient.addColorStop(0.25, 'orange');
gradient.addColorStop(0.375, 'yellow');
gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
gradient.addColorStop(0.625, 'yellow');
gradient.addColorStop(0.75, 'orange');
gradient.addColorStop(0.875, 'red');

ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillRect(10,10,200,100);
```

I want to find a way to have a balanced gradient, but the red part on the right side is bigger than the red part on the left side. Overall the gradient starts a bit too early or ends too soon, while the inputs seems to  indicate that it would be balanced.

I am surely missing something here.

Comment: Your gradient is an infinitely big rectangle. You define the colorstops area as 0 is at coords 0,0 and 1 at coords 200,0. Then you fill a rectangle from x:10 to x:200. You are indeed missing 0 to 0.05 part (the 10 first pixels). Either set your gradient's line coord correctly, either make your gradient move before filling, just as shown in the linked question/answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with the way `addColorStop` is meant to be used. Basically, you specify a point in the gradient, and the color it has to have at that point (see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasGradient/addColorStop). It does the transition before that point already. In your case specifically, it says e.g. that AT 0.125, your color should BE 'red', so it starts to transition to red before that (it seems to start transitioning at the previous stop. So it starts transitioning from red to orange at .125). So your percentage of red is 12.5 minus whatever it takes to transition. On the right side you say that AT 87.5% you should be back at red again. This means that after that, you have 12.5% of pure red since no further transition is specified, resulting in a wider section than on the left.

Hope it helps.